# Acessar Site Por Loggin

Tags: vba, excel-vba

não estou conseguindo acessar este site abaixo porque não localizo pelo VBA uma forma de inserir o Login e senha. Alguém saberia como acessar estes campos
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

https://www.newspace.com.br/pan/

eu tentei acessar procurando por frames, mas ainda sim não consegui acessar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente o seguinte código:

```
Private Sub AcessarSite()
    Dim driver As InternetExplorer
    Dim elem As HTMLBaseElement
    Dim url As String

    url = "https://www.newspace.com.br/pan/"

    Set driver = New InternetExplorer
    driver.Visible = True
    driver.Navigate url

 Set doc = driver.document.frames
 Set doc1 = doc.frames("Principal")

    doc1.document.getElementById("Usuario").innerText = "USUARIO CORRETO"
    doc1.document.getElementById("Senha").innerText = "SENHA CORRETA"
    doc1.document.getElementById("Ok").Click

    Set driver = Nothing
End Sub
```

Testei aqui e funcionou, o problemar era realmente com os frames.

Comment: Bom dia Marcelo, muito obrigado pela resposta e dedicação ao tema, infelizmente eu não estou conseguindo setar o login no site, ele me da um erro -> "Erro em tempo de execução '91': A variavel do objeto ou a variavel do bloco 'With' não foi definida". eu tentei utilizar o código com o Xpath "//*[@id='Usuario']" e com "html/body/form#f/table/tbody/tr/td/iframe/html/body/form#f/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input#Usuario" mas ambos retornam o mesmo erro

Comment: também não roda, ele da como "Erro em tempo de execução '424': O objeto é obrigatório", parece que para acessar este campo eu teria que acessar alguns iframe, mas mesmo tentando acessar esses iframes ele ainda não localiza o campo de login

Comment: Em vez de ie, tente driver, as vezes ele está dando erro por assumir ie como internet explorer e não uma variável

Comment: Desculpe Marcelo, mas não entendi bem o que você disse.

Comment: veja a resposta editada

Comment: Perfeito Marcelo, muito obrigado meu amigo, eu ja estava ficando louco com isso. Bora para outros desafios agora... vlw