# Como fazer login em site com VBA?

Tags: excel-vba

Bom dia pessoal. Estou com dificuldades para criar uma Macro VBA que faça login no site. Estou tentanto em um site de teste http://excelevba.com.br/download/login_teste.php. Até agora consegui apenas abrir o site com um comando de botão no excel, mas preciso que o mesmo, faça o login. Podem me ajudar?

Segue código abaixo

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim ie As Object
 Dim PaginaWeb As String


PaginaWeb = "http://excelevba.com.br/download/login_teste.php"

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
ie.navigate PaginaWeb

Do While Not ie.busy
  Loop
 'Do While ie.ReadyState <> 3
 'DoEvents
 'Loop
 ie.Visible = True

 'si se quiere cerrar la ventana
 'ie.quit

 Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249969/acessar-site-por-loggin), em que você precisa Inspecionar o elemento do site desejado (No Chrome Ctrl+Shift+I). No site da sua dúvida, a id de usuário é `user_exceleVBA`, senha `pwd_exceleVBA` e botão de enviar com id `submit`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Acessar Site Por Loggin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249969/acessar-site-por-loggin)

Comment: Outra diferença é que você não vai acessar o frame